# Adding updown/up/down icons to tablesorter table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

What's the minimal solution to add a clickable updown/up/down icon to the header of each sortable column of a [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/) table e.g. https://web.archive.org/web/20170112030141/http://jsfiddle.net/fu12ye88/ ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWxPV.png)) ?

All I've found are solutions requiring a relatively large additional libraries e.g. https://web.archive.org/web/20170112030034/http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/325/

Comment: You should not post code *just because the system requires it*. You should provide code so that it's clear what you're asking. You're just evading the requirements in a dirty way.

Comment: "You should not post code just because the system requires it. You should provide code so that it's clear what you're asking." What I'm asking is already clear (thanks in part to the jsfiddle link that mysteriously triggered this code requirement), and I can conceive of no code that would make it more so. Can you?

Comment: I'll take silence as a no.

Comment: Is this the sorter you're using https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/ ? If yes, I suppose this example is pretty easy to be simplified like your first jsfiddle.

Comment: If nothing else, post a picture... web.archive.org takes forever to load!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to [the docs](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) you'll find lots of ways to customize your sorted table.

I took the css out of the given example (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/) and applied some of it to your fiddle and [the result is exactly what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/fu12ye88/1/):

```
.tablesorter-default .header,
.tablesorter-default .tablesorter-header {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAJAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAkAAAIXjI+AywnaYnhUMoqt3gZXPmVg94yJVQAAOw==);
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
}

.tablesorter-default thead .headerSortUp,
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerAsc,
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerSortUp {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjI8Bya2wnINUMopZAQA7);
}

.tablesorter-default thead .headerSortDown,
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerDesc,
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerSortDown {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFQAEAIAAACMtMP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAVAAQAAAINjB+gC+jP2ptn0WskLQA7);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/fu12ye88/3/ , pic http://i.imgur.com/Rv8fzFS.png